# How to access the private access method in another activity?

Tags: android

I want to use a private access method in another activity !. But I don't know how to do it. Or what other way can I do it.
This is the AddSaleActivity property and the getAllItems () method is at its end.

```
public class AddSaleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button buttonInsert;
private RadioGroup radio_sale_type;
private RadioButton radio_benzin;
private RadioButton radio_gasOil;
private String sale_name;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sale);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GasStationDBHelper dbHelper = new GasStationDBHelper(this);
    mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    buttonInsert = findViewById(R.id.button_insert);
    radio_sale_type = findViewById(R.id.radio_group_ful_type);
    radio_benzin = findViewById(R.id.radio_benzin);
    radio_gasOil = findViewById(R.id.radio_gasOil);


    buttonInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItem();
        }
    });
}

private void addItem(){
    if (radio_sale_type.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "لطفا نوع سوخت را انتخاب کنید!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (radio_benzin.isChecked()){
        sale_name = "فروش بنزین";
    }
    if (radio_gasOil.isChecked()){
        sale_name = "فروش گازوئیل";
    }

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.COLUMN_NAME,sale_name);
    mDatabase.insert(GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    radio_sale_type.clearCheck();
    Toast.makeText(this, "فروش با موفقیت ثبت شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}

private Cursor getAllItems() {
    return mDatabase.query(
            GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
    );
}}
```

To create a view list I want to use getAllItems () in the HomeFragment in the adapter. But this method has private access and cannot be done

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<SaleItem> mSaleItems;
private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private GasStationAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mlayoutManager;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    //final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            //textView.setText(s);
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mAdapter = new GasStationAdapter(getContext(), AddSaleActivity.getAllItems());
    mAdapter.swapCursor(AddSaleActivity.getAllItems());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    createSaleList();
    //buildRecyclerView();


    return root;
}


public void createSaleList(){
    mSaleItems = new ArrayList<>();
    mSaleItems.add(new SaleItem("فروش بنزین", "1254000 تومان", "12450 لیتر"));
    mSaleItems.add(new SaleItem("فروش گازویبل", "175000 تومان", "5000 لیتر"));
    mSaleItems.add(new SaleItem("فروش بنزین", "1254000 تومان", "12450 لیتر"));
}

public void buildRecyclerView(){
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    //mAdapter = new SaleAdapter(mSaleItems);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}}
```

and this is the adapter

```
public class GasStationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GasStationAdapter.GasStationViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;

public GasStationAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
}

public class GasStationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView sale_nameText;

    public GasStationViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sale_nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_sale_name);
    }
}


@NonNull
@Override
public GasStationViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sale_item, parent, false);
    return new GasStationViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GasStationViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }
    String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
    holder.sale_nameText.setText(name);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
    }

    mCursor = newCursor;

    if (newCursor != null) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In the activity that have the private access method, add a public function with any name and inside it return the private access method u need so in that way you will be able to use it from anothet activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `SQLiteOpenHelper` a singleton:

```
class GasStationDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static volatile sInstance = null;

    static synchronized GasStationDBHelper instance(Context context) {
        if(sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new GasStationDBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        return sInstance;
    }

    Cursor getAllItems() {
        return getReadableDatabase().query(
            GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            GasStationContract.GasStationEntry.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"
    );
    }
}
```

Now, wherever you want the `Cursor`, just use `GasStationDBHelper.instance(context).getAllItems()`

**Edit:** Also, I wouldn't personally return a `Cursor`, but I'd map the result of your query to a data object so you can control ensuring the cursor is properly closed, i.e.:

```
List<Item> getAllItems() {
    try(Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC") {
        if(c == null || !c.moveToFirst)
            return new ArrayList<>();

        final List<Item> out = new ArrayList<>(c.getCount());
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            out.add(Item.fromCursorRow(c)); 
        }
        return out;
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This will help ensure you aren't leaking resources.

Answer (score 1):

Since `getAllItems()` doesn't depend on anything from Activity, why don't you just move this method inside of `GasStationDBHelper`. And then you can create `GasStationDBHelper` inside of Fragment and you can just call it there. You are using a database, so you can access the same data from anywhere in your project as long as you are operating on the same table.

If you need activity instance when you are creating `GasStationDBHelper`, then you can do it like this inside of fragment:

```
GasStationDBHelper dbHelper = new GasStationDBHelper(getActivity());
```

If an instance of activity needs to be `AddSaleActivity` then you can do it like this:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity instanceof AddSaleActivity) {
    GasStationDBHelper dbHelper = new GasStationDBHelper(activity (AddSaleActivity));
}
```

Also, I would recommend you move all operations on the database inside of `GasStationDBHelper` for a better separation in your project.

Comment: Also, make `GasStationDBHelper` singleton as is written in @PPartisan comment.